# Ms Access how to solve double row counting cause of DSum 'AND' (multiple criteria)

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access, expression

I'm working with Dsum expression, on a form. I want a combination results, SUM of 521213 (5212213 is records) each year (my choice field based). 
Here my expression:

```
=DSum("Input";"Q_RKLround";"MAK='521213'" AND "year= '" & [Form]![th] & "'")
```

but it expression show the results of **SUM = 521213 records + all year records** instead a combination. It result is wrong.
any idea how to fixed it?
thank you

Comment: Formatted code section.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 =DSum("Input";"Q_RKLround";"MAK='521213' AND year='" & [Form]![th] & "'")
```

There were a couple of double quotes that should not be there.

Also, is your year text or numerical? If it is numerical you should use

```
=DSum("Input";"Q_RKLround";"MAK='521213' AND year=" & [Form]![th])
```

Answer (score 0):

i was try both of its, n still get the double records counting..
each MAK 521213 of 2016 must be US$ 1.100
but cause of 'AND' it became USS 178.391